# MPID_nem_tcp_init(384).............: gethostbyname failed, Mac (errno 1)

Tags: macos, mpich

I install mpich3.3 locally on my macbook, but I got this run time error:

> Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
>
> MPIR_Init_thread(565)..............:
>
> MPID_Init(224).....................: channel initialization failed
>
> MPIDI_CH3_Init(105)................:
>
> MPID_nem_init(324).................:
>
> MPID_nem_tcp_init(178).............:
>
> MPID_nem_tcp_get_business_card(425):
>
> MPID_nem_tcp_init(384).............: gethostbyname failed, Mac (errno 1)

Could anyone please help me point out the issue and tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Is it because my terminal hostname is different from what I have in '/ect/host' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by adding a new line in the file `/etc/hosts`.

`1 ##
2 # Host Database
3 #
4 # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
5 # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
6 ##
7 127.0.0.1|  localhost
8 255.255.255.255|broadcasthost`

Simply add a new line `127.0.0.1       Mac`, where you need to replace `Mac` by your current machine name.

I believe this problem is caused by the modification of machine name from the system preference.